# Javascript Android Mozilla not opening page in a new tab

Tags: javascript, android, html, mozilla

So i am trying in JS and in HTML to make a **button** or **a** tag to open new tab in Default browser Androind and it's not working

This is my html and js code:

**HTML**

```
<button  class="btn btn-success a-new-tab" data-href="{{ $url }}">My btn</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.a-new-tab').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.open($(this).attr('data-href'), '_blank');
        window.focus();
    })
});
```

Please help me!

Comment: Are you being pop-up blocker blocked?

Comment: I don't understand, when i am pressing the button just current page is going to another but not opening new tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a same issue on iPhone/iPad Safari browser, so the below solution worked for me. Perhaps, it might help you as well.

**HTML**

```
<button class="a-new-tab" data-href="https://www.google.com/">My btn</button>
```

On `button` click, I'm getting the `data-href` and then set `onclick` attribute to the same button, and inside the attribute opening a new window

```
$(".a-new-tab").on("click", function () {        
    var url = $(this).attr("data-href");
    $(this).attr( "onclick", "window.open('" + url + "'); return false;" );
});
```